# ORA-01841: (full) year must ... not be 0. How to reproduce and to fix?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

sorry for asking a question, that has a lot of answers on Stackoverflow and allow me to pose this question in my context, that may differ from the previous questions.

I'm on a Production database, where I CANNOT CHANGE data. The data going into this database is highly dynamic, it changes all the time, so that makes it hard to reproduce that error. I'm accessing **Oracle 11g** via JDBC (Java).

Ok, for my DELETE I get the

```
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0.
```

This is my table (simplified):

```
MY_TABLE 
Name                         Null?    Type                        
---------------------------- -------- --------------------------- 
MYTIMESTAMP                  NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
```

From time to time I get the ORA-01841 for this DELETE:

```
delete from MY_TABLE where MYTIMESTAMP < sysdate - 30
```

When I look up the data, all seems fine. So where I need an idea:

1) How can I insert an invalid timestamp into MY_TABLE, so that I can reproduce that error? (*)

2) How can I rewrite the DELETE statement, so that I won't fail? Please note, I cannot change the existing data on Oracle.

Thank you

(*) I tried to insert these "invalid" date, but alas, not invalid enough:

```
insert into MY_TABLE (MY_IMESTAMP) values ('31-DEC-9999 11:00:00 PM +2:00')
insert into MY_TABLE (MY_IMESTAMP) values ('31-DEC-0 11:00:00 PM +2:00')
```

Comment: Sounds like you might have corrupt data? Curious that it's intermitent, unless there are other filters and it's consistent depending on those values. When the problem is occurring it would be interesting to see what `dump()` shows, and also whether changing to `where MYTIMESTAMP < systimestamp - interval '30' days` (avoiding implicit conversion) also errors.

Comment: what if you write a query to extract the year value frommytimestamp where the value is outside the valid range, and see what comes back?

Comment: >avoiding implicit conversion ( `systimestamp - interval '30' days` ).
Yep, sounds good. I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: Something else to check is whether there is a trigger that is actually throwing the error, perhaps because it does some other conversion, possibly relying on NLS settings. So not necessarily related to the actual timestamp at all. You might be able to tell from the error stack; I'm not sure how much JDBC shows you...

Comment: If you don't care about the time portion, you can try trunc dates. See if you still get the error.

Comment: Alex and Sam: Thanks for your insight here. I will look that up (NLS) or try it (TRUNC, time portion is in fact not relevant here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that error a lot when there are implicit type conversions going on. Can you maybe try:

```
delete from MY_TABLE where MYTIMESTAMP < systimestamp - interval '30' day
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that this week. Unfortunately I cannot try it by myself (don't have access to that database directly) and  'Accept' this answer right away.